# label loop for next visual basic

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, label, newline

Currently my code looks like this:

```
Private Sub btnMotivate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMotivate.Click
    Dim intNumber As Integer
    Dim strStudy As String = "Study!"

    intNumber = InputBox("How many times do you want to be motivated? Please use numbers!")
    If intNumber < 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please use a number from 1 - 10!")
    End If
    If intNumber > 10 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please use a number from 1 - 10!")
    End If

>    For intCounter = 1 To intNumber Step 1
        lblMotivation.Text = strStudy
>    Next

End Sub
```

As you can see, I have added a variable and the loop runs fine, but I need help phrasing the code so whatever number the user inputs, is the number of lines of "Study!" displayed. I have tried using the string but also using the label with Environment.NewLine hoping it would add a new line every time the loop runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the label text to `strStudy` each time. This doesn't add to what's there already, it just replaces it.

You need to add `strStudy` to the text that already exists, something like this:

```
' start with an empty string
lblMotivation.Text = ""
For intCounter = 1 To intNumber Step 1
    ' append the study string and a newline
    lblMotivation.Text = lblMotivation.Text & strStudy & Environment.NewLine
Next
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this was very helpful and very simple

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a TextBox, use a ListBox to display the word Study! n -times. It is also good practice not to instruct the user to do something, but prevent it in code. Also note how intNumber has been changed to **inp**Number As Object

```
Private Sub btnMotivate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnMotivate.Click
    Dim inpNumber As Object
    Dim strStudy As String = "Study!"
    Dim intCounter As Integer 
    inpNumber = InputBox("How many times do you want to be motivated?")
    If Not IsNumeric(inpNumber) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number!")
    ElseIf inpNumber < 1 OrElse inpNumber > 10 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number from 1 - 10!")
    Else
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        For intCounter = 1 To inpNumber Step 1
            ListBox1.Items.Add(strStudy)
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The reason I have to do the input the way I do is because this assignment (I'm in high school, computer programming 1 class) tells us to specifically "Verify the user entered a number between 1 and 10 – show a message if they did not."

Comment: I made some changes you may find useful. What if the user enters a letter, "s" for example instead of a number. Your code will throw an exception. Try it. Also if you use a TextBox to contain the results, you will see the word study! repeated on the same line, whether you include Environment.NewLine or not. You should test answers before accepting them.